# HttpCalloutMock not being used

Tags: apex, rest-api, webservices

I have a class that mocks a response to a callout in my test class. However it is not being used when the response is returned. Another piece of code is returning the response and it is not correct.

My mock class:

```
@isTest
global class mockClass implements HttpCalloutMock{

    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
        String body = 'my body is in here';
        response.setBody(body);
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        return response;
    } 
}
```

This code is in the same class where the callout occurs which provides me with an incorrect response:

```
if (!Test.isRunningTest()){
    response = http.send(request);
}
else{
    response = new HttpResponse();
    response.setStatusCode(200);
    response.setBody('Incorrect response which is being used')
}
```

When I run my test class with the mock, it is never used. Is there a way to this instead of the incorrect way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of the mock is that you don't need to use Test.isRunningTest to block off the callout. Change your code to simply:

```
response = http.send(request);
```

The if-else shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense